# Saving multi-dimensional array into text file add extra columns

Tags: java, matrix, text-files

I have a task that requires me to pass an array with `double` values into a text file in Java. I used `BufferedWriter` for this task, but the problem is that I am getting extra columns with zero values in the text file.

For example, if I try to write the following data to the text file:

```
1.0, 2.0, 3.0
2.0, 1.0, 1.0
3.0, 2.0, 2.0
```

I get the following results:

```
1.0,2.0,3.0
2.0,1.0,1.0
3.0,2.0,2.0
0.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,0.0
```

Here is the code that I used:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    File file1 = new File("file.txt"); 
        Scanner sc  = null;    
        sc = new Scanner( file1);        
        String  line = "";
        int maxLen = 0;
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            line = sc.nextLine();
            list.add(line);
            if(line.length() > maxLen)
                maxLen = line.length(); 
        }
        System.out.println(list); 
        int rows = maxLen;
        int col = list.size();
        double arr[][] = new double[rows][col];
        rows = 0; 
        for(int i=0;i<col;i++)
        {
            String s = list.get(i); 
            String []values = s.split(", "); 
            if(rows < values.length)
                rows = values.length; 
            for(int j=0;j<values.length;j++)
            {
                if (!values[j].isEmpty()) {
                arr[j][i] = Double.parseDouble(values[j]);

                }
                }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j]+", ");// displaying numbers

            }
            System.out.println();

        }

File filename = new File("FinalTopFeatures1.txt");
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      bw.write(arr[i][j] + ((j == arr[i].length-1) ? "" : ","));
   }
   bw.newLine();
}
bw.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the length of the array (`arr.length`). It is writing the whole array which is containing zero values. If you don't want to write all the zero values then: either you can reduce the arr size or iterate the for loop only for the number of rows it contains data. Suppose for your case only 3 rows contains data. so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      bw.write(arr[i][j] + ((j == col-1) ? "" : ","));
   }
   bw.newLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ruhul . But the number of rows is changeable because this code is running inside another code. I just put a sample from the data

Comment: Well that could be changeable. But I guess you could know how many of rows contains data. It will be good for us if you paste the code from where you are inserting data into this `arr`. @sally

Comment: The "other" code almost certainly must have been keeping track of how many rows it actually put into `arr`; you want to run your loop up to that count, rather than up to `arr.length`.  The big question, then, will be whether or not that count is conveniently available for your new code to use.

Comment: I updated my code started from where I am inserting data into this arr @ruhul

Comment: Also when printing the arr in the text area no extra zero column are got. just when I save the arr in the text file

Comment: I've updated answer accordingly. Please check @sally

Comment: sorry it printed only the last line for the array

Comment: Thanks @ruhul. I reconise  the error rows1 not rows. Now it is working and the answer will be accepted

Comment: Most Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

For performance ideal, you should comprehend it. I just try to fix your problem here.

```
for (double[] doubles : arr) {
    for (int j = 0; j < doubles.length; j++) {
        double value = doubles[j];
        boolean takeAll = (value - (int) value) > 0;

        if (takeAll)
            bw.write(value + ((j == doubles.length - 1) ? "" : ","));
        else
            bw.write((int) value + ((j == doubles.length - 1) ? "" : ","));
    }
    bw.newLine();
}
```

Comment: [[1.0, 2.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[3.0, 2.0, 2.0]]` will your code work for this case?

Comment: Thanks but still getting the same outputs with extra zeros columns

Comment: the output for my sample data above shold be like the following 
1.0,2.0,3.0
2.0,1.0,1.0
3.0,2.0,2.0

Answer (score 0):

A row will be invalid and ignored if all its elements are 0. So, you might add a counter to increase in one if the current value is equals to 0, and if the counter is equals to the row length by the end of the loop you could say that this row is invalid and it must not be write on the file.

```
try {
        File filename = new File("FinalTopFeatures1.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));

        // The variable has been initialized for test porpuses
        double arr[][] = new double[][] {
            { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 },
            { 2.0, 1.0, 1.0 },
            { 3.0, 2.0, 2.0 },
            { 0, 0, 0 },
            { 1.0, 1.0, -2 },
        };

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int invalidValueCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                if (arr[i][j] == 0) invalidValueCount++;
                builder.append(arr[i][j]).append((j == arr[i].length - 1) ? "" : ",");
            }

            if (invalidValueCount < arr[i].length) {
                bw.write(builder.toString());
                bw.newLine();
            }
            invalidValueCount = 0;
            builder.setLength(0);
        }
        bw.close();
    } catch (Exception io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I've used a StringBuilder to save the row as String in case the row is valid.

Comment: I cant put the data inside the array arr[][] , this just a sample and the original one is quite big

Comment: I've initialized the variable to test and as an example, but it will work with any data